# Keep Layout of extracted text in pdfminer.six python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, text, pdfminer

I want to extract the text of this pdf: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/files/1887670/Wochenkarte-KW-15-Neu.pdf

When I extract the text using this code:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    device = None
    try:
        with StringIO() as string_writer, open(path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            device = TextConverter(resource_manager, string_writer, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams())
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, device)

            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(pdf_file, maxpages=1):
                interpreter.process_page(page)

            pdf_text = string_writer.getvalue()
    finally:
        if device:
            device.close()
    return pdf_text
```

The text corresponds not to the text layout of the pdf.
Current Result:

```
Montag 09.04.2018 
Menü 1 

Kl. Salat 


Menü 2 

Kl. Salat 

Seelachs-Spinat-Türmchen mit Spinat-
Masalla-Sauce und Reis 
Currywurst mit Pommes
```

Expected Result:

```
Montag 09.04.2018 
Menü 1 

Kl. Salat Seelachs-Spinat-Türmchen mit Spinat-Masalla-Sauce und Reis 

Menü 2 

Kl. Salat Currywurst mit Pommes
```

What do I do wrong or am I missing something else?

Comment: I think you're just running into the properties of PDFs here. PDFs don't have a real layout, it's just a bunch of words on a page. PDF extractors do their best to guess the layout from that but they often can't

Comment: Can I somehow influence pdfminer's "guessing"? 
For example if I use website pdftotext.com everything looks fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is giving another linemargin in LAParams:

```
LAParams(line_margin=0.1)
```

My line looks now like this:

```
device = TextConverter(resource_manager, string_writer, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams(line_margin=0.1))
```

Credits to [Tim](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/138#issuecomment-380294901)